# Regex to extract attribute value

Tags: c#, html, regex

What would be a quick way to extract the value of the title attributes for an HTML table:

```
...
<li><a href="/wiki/Proclo" title="Proclo">Proclo</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Proclus" title="Proclus">Proclus</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Ptolemy" title="Ptolemy">Ptolemy</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Pythagoras" title="Pythagoras">Pythagoras</a></li></ul><h3>S</h3>
...
```

so it would return Proclo, Proclus, Ptolemy, Pythagoras,.... in strings for each line. I'm reading the file using a StreamReader. I'm using C#.

Thank you.

Comment: And in what form do you have your html table? (ASP controls, strings, stream, XmlReader, DOM?)

Comment: \*Sigh\*... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 for the (1/epsilon)th time.

Comment: @delnan: excellent point. However, the post linked to seems to have been corrupted? It isn't showing correctly in my browser

Comment: @sehe: That post has numerous obscure unicode characters sprinkled in for effects, laughs and as a reference to [some weird meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/zalgo). It's intended to look broken.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This C# regex will find all title values:

```
(?<=\btitle=")[^"]*
```

The C# code is like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\btitle="")[^""]*");
Match match = regex.Match(input);
string title = match.Value;
```

The regex uses *positive lookbehind* to find the position where the `title` value starts. It then matches everything up to the ending double quote.

Answer (score 12):

Use the regexp below

```
title="([^"]+)"
```

and then use **Groups** to browse through matched elements.

EDIT: I have modified the regexp to cover the examples provided in comment by @Staffan Nöteberg

Comment: It's OK for the examples, which is probably enough. But won't work with `<li><a href="/wiki/Proclo" title="Proclo" attr="value">Proclo</a></li>` or `<li><a title="Proclus" href="/wiki/Proclus">Proclus</a></li>`.

Comment: @Staffan Nöteberg Good point, now it should also cover your examples.