# Regex c# html tags with specific attribute

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am new to Regular expression:( After lot of search for my requirement I was able to manage get answer but i do get extra results as explained below:

My String

```
<td valign="top" width="100%">
<td width="100%" valign="top">
<td valign="top" height="100%" width="100%">
<td valign="top">
```

My Expression

```
/<td (?=.*valign="top")(?=.*width="100%").*>/gm
```

My Result

```
<td valign="top" width="100%">
<td width="100%" valign="top">
<td valign="top" height="100%" width="100%">
```

Expected result

```
<td valign="top" width="100%">
<td width="100%" valign="top">
```

Conclusion: I want to extract TD tag that has valign and width attribute only with specific value.

Note : I have to parse through lots of data file hence HTMLAgility will slow down overall process.

Kindly guide me to final expression. Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to extract attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526094/regex-to-extract-attribute-value)

Comment: I would not be so sure about *HTMLAgility will slow down overall process* if you *have to parse through lots of data file*. Well, it's your choice, I'd go with HtmlAgilityPack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be doing it for me:

```
\<td\s+((valign="top"\s+width="100%")|(width="100%"\s+valign="top"))\s*>\gm
```

Your expression searches to see if the two attributes are somewhere ahead of the `<td` beginning. This one allows for whitespace, then searches for either `valign="top" width="100%"` or `width="100%" valign="top"`, followed by more optional whitespace before the end of the td tag. This disallows all attributes except for the width and valign attributes.

With that said, there are always unexpected situations when using regex. You can test your regex expressions in real-time here: http://regexr.com/ Just type in your string and the regex expression to see what it selects.

EDIT:

If you want to account for both single quotes and double quotes around the attributes, try this one:

```
\<td\s+((valign=([",'])top\3\s+width=([",'])100%\4)|(width=([",'])100%\6\s+valign=([",'])top\7))\s*>\gm
```

Now I'm allowing for either a " or ' at the beginning of the attribute's value, and search for a match of whichever one was found at the end of the attribute's value.

Again, I encourage you to go to the website I linked above and play around with these yourself as well. I almost never use regex, but when I do I can usually find an expression that works for me with that website.

Comment: Thanks Matt...You answer suffice my requirement...Cheers